# Resizing Virtual drive

Tags: virtualbox

I am running Ubuntu as a guest on an iMac with VirtualBox version 4.1.8.

What is the easiest way to resize the virtual drive?

Please provide as much detail as possible including the correct format for any commands.

Comment: I would do it piping tar -cf across disks, but I'm sure there's a better way to do it.

Comment: I had the same question, running Ubuntu as a guest on a Windows 7 host. @Joni's answer was a great help, with the addition of http://askubuntu.com/questions/154921/how-do-i-get-ubuntu-12-04-to-recognize-swap-partition-so-that-i-can-hibernate to get the swap working again.

Answer (score 97):

This answer is directed at a Windows host, but if you use bash in place of the PowerShell and replace '\' with '/' it should work just fine.

Enlarge virtual drive

1. **From VirtualBox**

   1. Release the VDI file: File -> Virtual Media Manager -> Select VDI -> Release
   2. Copy the location of the VDI inside the properties box 'C:\Users\campbell\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu14\Ubuntu14.vdi'
   3. Backup the VDI file

      1. Copy the VDI file to a new location.
      2. Assign a new UUID to the original VDI file:

         1. Start `Powershell` (not as an administrator):
         2. Change to your Oracle VirtualBox directory `cd  C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox`
         3. `.\VBoxManage.exe internalcommands sethduuid "C:\Users\campbell\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu14\Ubuntu14.vdi"`
   4. Remove and re-add your machine's .vdi file to update its UUID.

      1. File -> Virtual Media Manager -> Select VDI -> Remove
      2. Apply.
      3. Right click your VM -> Configuration -> Storage -> Controller: SATA -> Add new hard drive. Select your .vdi file.
2. **From host**

   1. Work out desired size: you can google it, eg. '40 Gb=MB' returns 40000 MB
   2. Start `PowerShell` (not as administrator)
   3. Change to your Oracle VirtualBox directory `cd C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox`
   4. Resize your .vdi file `.\VBoxManage.exe modifyhd "C:\Users\campbell\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu14\Ubuntu14.vdi" --resize 40000`
   5. Now start your virtual machine. You will receive the same warning about space that prompted you to engage in this procedure. Not to worry, we are near the end.
3. **On your virtual machine**

   1. Start the partition manager `gparted` (install it if is is missing `sudo apt-get install gparted`)
   2. Get rid of the swap partition, which prevents you from expanding the root partition. Note that you cannot harm the rest of your machine - this is all happening inside a single file. Worst case scenario you trash this file and you have to use your backup instead.

      1. Make a note of the size of the linux-swap partition 4 GiB in my case
      2. Right click on it and `Swapoff`
      3. Right click on it and `Delete`
      4. Apply by clicking on the checkmark (Apply all operations). Ignore the dire warning - life is too short to indulge Cassandras
      5. right click on the extended file system that once housed the swap partition (/dev/sda2 in all likelihood) and delete it
      6. right click on the root partition (/dev/sda1) and resize it. Tab to the 'Free space following' field and enter the size of the swap partition. Shift-Tab and the machine will work out the new size for you automatically.
      7. Right click in the unallocated space at the end and make it an extended partition
      8. Right click in the new partition and select `linux-swap` in the File system field.
      9. Commit your changes as before
      10. Right click on your swap partition and select `swapon`
      11. Tell the Fat Lady to commence singing.

#### References:

1. https://tinyapps.org/blog/misc/201204120700_virtualbox_increase_disk_space.html
2. [Resize Ubuntu 10.04 VirtualBox VM virtual disk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/219880/resize-ubuntu-10-04-virtualbox-vm-virtual-disk)

Comment: Worked, with a few extra steps (1.1) I had to remove the VDI and then add it back to the virtual machine after giving it a new uuid and resizing it. (1.5) I had to cd into c:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15074878/virtual-box-uuid-07c3-does-not-match-the-value-2c1b-stored-in-th

Comment: This one is freaking awesome answer !!!

Comment: Very good description but you can shorten it to: ".\VBoxManage modifyhd myUbuntu14.vdi --resize 40000" followed by the steps under point "3. On your virtual machine". Nevertheless I gave you an upvote for your good answer

Comment: Very good answer. You've saved my day.

Comment: Note that you may have to activate swap and edit /etc/fstab after doing this https://askubuntu.com/a/819689/100362

Comment: Your answer is awesome! I just spent last hour to read lots of posts but couldn't fix this issue, and now I have done it with your step based instructions. Thank you.

Comment: Worked great for me, and I didn't have to re-install my debian guest!

Comment: This looks like a great answer but on #1 of 3 I cannot install gparted because No space left on device which is the original problem using me to find his issue.

Comment: I didn't have a swap partition to start with, but the rest worked fine! Edit: I used Ubuntu on top of a Windows Host with Hyper-V Paravirtualization.

Answer (score 47):

If you are making the disk bigger, you would

1. first enlarge the disk from VirtualBox, and then
2. enlarge the partition, and
3. the filesystem it contains.

To enlarge a disk you can use the [`VBoxManage modifyhd`](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-modifyvdi) command. Suppose you want to resize the disk to 20,000 megabytes (~20GB). First locate the disk file that you want to expand. Then, in terminal, give this command to resize the disk:

```
VBoxManage modifyhd "path-of-disk-file" --resize 20000
```

To enlarge the partition and file system, probably it's easiest to boot the virtual machine using a Ubuntu livecd and do the job with GParted, as it does both at the same time and gives you a graphical user interface for it.

Attach a livecd ISO image to the virtual machine and change the boot order to first boot from CD. If you don't have a Ubuntu livecd at hand you can use any livecd that comes with the appropriate tools. [SliTAZ](http://www.slitaz.org/en/) for example is only 35MB to download. Open GParted and choose the disk you want to resize. Then right-click on the partition that you want to expand and choose the option "resize-move." In the dialog box that opens, in the graphic that represents the partition, drag the triangle at the end of the partition all the way to the right to maximize it. Then close the dialog and choose "Apply" on the toolbar. Since no data has to be moved this should be a quick operation.

When done, don't forget to detach the livecd from the virtual machine and change the boot order.

You'll find a pretty good tutorial of the whole process with screenshots included here: http://trivialproof.blogspot.com/2011/01/resizing-virtualbox-virtual-hard-disk.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. While some info is given here, a bit more info would be good, in case the blog you linked to is down.

Comment: What information would you add?

Comment: I recommend the main steps from the instructions so that if the blog were taken down, anyone viewing this answer would be able to fix their issue. This helps avoid [linkrot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linkrot)

Comment: @ObsessiveFOSS Better now?

Comment: +1 It looks much better now.

Comment: I used these instructions to resize my virtual disk. During the process I had to delete the swap partition to enable me to expand the root partition. I found the instructions relating to http://askubuntu.com/questions/154921/how-do-i-get-ubuntu-12-04-to-recognize-swap-partition-so-that-i-can-hibernate helpful to get swap working again.

Comment: Realised the previous link to get swap working wasn't exactly what I wanted. It was for making swap work with hibernation. The answer to this question is more what I was looking for: http://askubuntu.com/questions/180730/how-do-i-restore-a-swap-partition-i-accidentally-deleted.

Comment: I had to remove the *.vdi images from Virtual Box (v4.1.12) before VBoxManage modifyhd would work without spitting a fatal error at me. Use VirtualBox's File > Virtual Media Manager to bring up a dialog where you can remove the association.

Comment: i vote up your answer but i recommend to install gparted in the ubuntu guest vm and with sudo just resize the disk (and delete and create at the end the swap partition), take only 2 minutes including the apt-get install :) )

Comment: I followed the blog instructions but I had swap partition. The resize/move didn't work so I had  to resize the extended partition to also use unnaloccated size, then move swap partition all the way to the right, then shrink the extended partition back to what it was and finally I could use that unnaloccated size to the main partition.