# How do I get Ubuntu 12.04 to recognize encrypted swap partition so that I can hibernate?

Tags: 12.04, swap

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 and used gparted to erase and enlarge my swap partition.  When I rebooted, gparted said that the file partition for the swap was unknown.  Gparted doesn't let me change the file partition to "linux-swap".  It does let me change it to NTFS, but when I reboot, it goes back to "unknown".  Thanks in advance for your help.

Output from `sudo swapon -s`:

```
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1                  partition   9025532 0   -1
```

Output from `sudo fdisk -l`:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 250.1 GB, 250059350016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 30401 cylinders, total 488397168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x9d63ac84

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048     2459647     1228800    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2         2459648   197836472    97688412+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       466890752   488395119    10752184    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       197836798   466890751   134526977    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       197836800   448837631   125500416   83  Linux
/dev/sda6       448839680   466890751     9025536   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Partition table entries are not in disk order

Disk /dev/mapper/cryptswap1: 9242 MB, 9242148864 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1123 cylinders, total 18051072 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x951b7f53

Disk /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

Comment: Have a look at this - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnableHibernateWithEncryptedSwap

Comment: @Kayla,@Elfy : Can you elaborate the comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though you are using encrypted swap because of the "cryptswap1." A random access key is generated on suspend to access encrypted swap upon resume. Sometimes this random key is lost in the system. I would suggest creating a passphrase that you will need to enter manually upon resume. This will show you step by step how to create an encrypted swap partition and set it's pass phrase.

Source: http://www.ubuntulinuxguide.com/make-ubuntu-12-04-recognize-encrypted-swap-partitions-to-enable-hibernation/