# How do I restore a swap partition I accidentally deleted?

Tags: partitioning, gparted, swap

I accidentally deleted my swap partition via gparted.

**(I'm still logged in the system so restoring should be easier)** Can someone help me please? I'm not sure how to configure it because the Ubuntu installation did it automatically.

There are 3 partitions right now:

```
  /dev/sda1 -> Ubuntu installation root, mounted at '/'

  /dev/sda2 -> Windows partition

  /dev/sda3 -> Fedora partition
```

and `/dev/sda4` if im not mistaken was the swap partition (4GB size)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Just use gparted again to create the additional `/dev/sda4` partition, and format it as type "linux swap".

**Example:**

- Here, I deleted the my `/dev/sda6` swap partition in the highlighted space:

  [image]
- Right-click on that unallocated space, and click on New; choose type "linux-swap", click on Add:

  [image]
- Apply changes
- Right-click on the new swap partition and choose "swapon":

  [image]
- Unless you removed it, the swap entry in `/etc/fstab` should still be there.

  - Check from the terminal with: `grep swap.*sw /etc/fstab`, and you should see a long line like:

  ```
  UUID=adc15cab-1cd4-4278-9a1d-59016cced6dd none swap sw  0  0
  ```

  - If you *do not* see such a line, obtain the UUID using `sudo blkid | grep swap`, and *add* a line in this format to `/etc/fstab`.
  - If you do see such a line, but the UUID does not match what was returned by `blkid`, then edit fstab to match.  (Note: The line in fstab should not be commented out, i.e., it should not start with #.)
- Run `free -m` to verify the swap partition is active.

Comment: I dont see the swap partition listed in fstab. The only sda* entry in fstab is sda1 (which is the root '/' )

Comment: @Varemenos: please see edited answer.

Comment: @izx cool! Thanks for the tricks! I applied it with a recent resized VM ubuntu in VirtualBox! It works like a charm!