# Hibernate no longer works

Tags: 13.04, hibernate

I've enabled the hibernate option and have successfully used it multiple times before, but for some reason when I tried it a few minutes ago, it only locked the computer. Running `sudo pm-hibernate` seemed to do literally nothing--it asked for my password, then returned to the prompt immediately after I entered it. I think this has happened before, but I don't remember what I did to fix it (if I really did anything). I need to boot Windows, but I've got stuff open and really don't want to do a full reboot. What's going on, and how could I fix this?

Comment: Duplicate: [How to enable hibernation?](http://askubuntu.com/q/94754/159545). Please *search* AskUbuntu (top right, search bar) before opening a new question.

Comment: @edwin I've already enabled it, and it's worked before, it just stopped working today (or some time in the past few days, between when I last successfully hibernated and now).

Comment: Then please edit your question to specify that you made hibernate work *on* Raring, and that it stop working *on* Raring. As is, it's somewhat ambiguous. Anyway, have you updated or changed your system in any way (on which you may attribute the missing hibernate)? Also edit your question to include your PC model/specs.

Comment: @edwin `sudo pm-hibernate` has always worked. "Enabling" hibernate just put a button for it in Unity's menu. All I've done recently is install whatever updates the update manager finds.

Answer (score 1):

One of the most common reasons of hibernate not working even after enabling by using the method [xchamitha mentioned](https://askubuntu.com/a/325571/72576) is either a missing swap partition or a missing entry for the [swap](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq) partition in your `/etc/fstab` file. This can happen if you ever modified your swap partition by deleting, extending, recreating it. Even if you haven't, **verify**.

Check if you have the correct entry in your `/etc/fstab` by opening a terminal(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) and then type:

```
sudo blkid
```

this will give you an output such this(this is mine, your's will have different number of partitions with different UUID's):

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="E8EE-D6B7" TYPE="vfat" 
/dev/sda2: LABEL="Windows and Components" UUID="CAE8DFDDE8DFC63B" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda4: LABEL="Peripherals and Support" UUID="01CEB0A39FEAB500" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="dcce3bed-77bd-497a-af91-6de6a1a68617" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda6: UUID="85b5c13d-93ed-487b-a4b2-9004a1fd27b0" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda7: UUID="7301ea57-3526-4336-b541-1e8a0422e402" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda8: UUID="b23adddf-2164-46ab-aa3a-bd8d83158d22" TYPE="swap"
```

the last entry is of the swap partition. Note the UUID of the swap partition(it is `b23adddf-2164-46ab-aa3a-bd8d83158d22` for mine). If you don't have such a line, you don't have a swap partition and you will need to create one using either [the GUI method](https://askubuntu.com/a/180735/72576) or [the command-line method](https://askubuntu.com/a/33703/72576).

Next, check if there is a line in your `/etc/fstab` file similar to this:

```
UUID=b23adddf-2164-46ab-aa3a-bd8d83158d22 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

This line tells the kernel to mount the swap partition on boot, which is important for hibernation to be available. The entries here are separated by space(s)(the number of spaces does not matter, you should have at least one space between two entries).

Once you have completed this, reboot your machine and you should have an entry to  hibernate.

Comment: Did exactly that but still can't hibernate. I increased my swap size, added the new UUID into the /etc/fstab but still can't hibernate.

Comment: @user240955: What do you get when you type `sudo pm-hibernate` on  a terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Try following, this blogpost on how to enable hibernate in ubuntu 13.04. http://xchamitha.blogspot.co.uk/2013/07/enabling-hybernate-in-ubuntu-1304.html.

To summarise:

**Enabling Hybernate in Ubuntu 13.04**

Open a terminal <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type,

```
sudo gedit /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/hibernate.pkla
```

Paste the following and save the file.

```
[Re-enable Hibernate]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes
```

Reboot your computer.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/94754/how-to-enable-hibernation#comment430252_94963