# Can swap be on a different disk?

Tags: swap

I have 16GB of RAM and the core system is run on 128GB sddisk. So I don't have space to use 16/32 GB for swap.

Can I create swap on another hard disk? Or it has to be on the same disk as the system?

**EDIT**

What are the steps to migrate swap from `/dev/sdc3` to `/dev/sdb`. The file `fstab` looks like this

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=6d9c9f84-02f0-4f59-b57f-6a4ebd06b87f /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=4B73-5222  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults        0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda4 during installation
UUID=b0233bff-100f-4741-ad00-29ffc6f26057 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=1a3ad087-9ba3-4312-9307-a84dade9e1bf none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Comment: hmmm... I've yet to see a linux installation where the 'core system' would take over 30 GB space :)

Comment: You are right about core system, but I meant to `/home` as well which is on the sddisk and already consumed 30GB of space (out of 70GB).

Comment: Take a look at [How to increase swap space?](http://askubuntu.com/q/178712/61060) as it could be best solution for almost any situation nowdays. Of course you could also create multiple swap partitions and/or files (using different physical storage media) to make it faster.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.

You can choose to do this at the time of installation, or you can make a swap partition with a tool such as `gparted` and then activate the swap with `swapon`. Add it to your `fstab` to make it available on boot.

For help with making the swap partition: [How do I restore a swap partition I accidentally deleted?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180730/how-do-i-restore-a-swap-partition-i-accidentally-deleted)

For help with turning swap on: You literally just type `sudo swapon` into a terminal

For help with adding to your fstab: [How do I add a swap partition after system installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33697/how-do-i-add-a-swap-partition-after-system-installation)

Comment: Can you write a step to migrate swap from `sdc3` to `sdb` disk?

Comment: Just edited my post, let me know if those links help

Answer (score 5):

Since you have 16GB of RAM, there is no need for a 'swap' partition. Also, the 'swap should be 1-2 times the RAM' rule is only valid for systems having less RAM, ie < 2GB.

You can create a swap partition on a separate drive by using `mkswap` and `swapon`.

Eg - To to migrate swap from /dev/sdc3 to /dev/sdb1 -

`swapoff /dev/sdc3`

`mkswap /dev/sdb1`

`swapon /dev/sdb1`

and edit swap entry in /etc/fstab.

Comment: I am trying to enable hibernate and the system is not waking so I read that I have to make swap as large as RAM to make hibernate work. Now, how do you set the size of swap? Do I have to make `swapon` on each startup?

Comment: Create a new partition in the drive ie /dev/sdb1. Now, use the commands `mkswap` and `swapon` to create a swap partition and edit the `fstab` entry so that the system knows where the swap is located. This is a one-time process.

Comment: You can set the size at creation time.