# Partition not showing after fresh installation

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount, hard-drive

I have just install Ubuntu in my new works station and having issue with showing up all available partitions and mount it.

As I am not well experienced with Ubuntu, I am unable to understand the reason and how to do it. :(

I have total 3 hard drive 1TB, 1TB and 500GB first 1TB has two partition and Windows is installed on one of them.

2nd hard drive of 500GB has no partition and set for my work archive

3rd hard drive of 1TB dedicated using for and created two partition roughly 500GB each by following this [How to Install Ubuntu on separate hard drive in a dual boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/312782/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-separate-hard-drive-in-a-dual-boot) during the installation

Now I am having problem to see the second partition of Ubuntu hard drive (1TB / 500GB + 500GB)

I have checked in Disk manager but have no idea what is showing it. It is showing 3 partition of 500GB each. Please see attached images.

### Disk manager

[image]

### It seems incomplete to me! See the partition edit window. Is it?

[image]

### Available / mounted drive

[image]

Can anyone help me to fix it and make available all partition and mount it.

Thanks

## Updated - made some changes based on provided answer

So here I have removed swap and other partition so I have now two partition 1 500GB for `/` ( I think) and another is unallocated.

[image]

Can you please guide how and what `File system` I should choose.

Million thanks.!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resize partitions?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]welcome, assuming you are using a 4 gb RAM computer, you will have delete that 500GB patition indicating SWAP , the right click on the unlocated new 500Gb which will appear in grey color and allocated 4 gb as swap by selecting file system as Linux-Swap in G-Parted and click add, the remaining vlume you will create a new file system by right clicking on it and select new same as but this time the file system should be ext-4 file system since its for your files then click the green tick top there to complete .[image]

Comment: You are amazing. Such help I was looking for with some reference. I have followed your step and all set. Just last quick question. Do I need to active `swap` partition or not require?

Comment: Anytime. in your terminal type sudo blkid to view your SWAP UUID, then open a new terminal tab and type sudo gedit /etc/fstab , the UUID of SWAP in blkid should match the one in /etc/fstab if not copy the UUID of SWAP you obtained in blkid and replace it in /etc/fstab

Comment: This is another new thing I learn. UUID for ext4 was the same but for the swap. I have replaced `fstab` by copying from `blkid` is there any other step require?

Comment: you are done (:(: just restart your pc

Answer (score 3):

The reason you cant view it is because its been allocated for swap which is a waste allocating it 500GB its good to allocate it a size equal to RAM size of your PC. Re partition that 1Tb disks 500GB extended prtition in live mode by using Gparted and allocated a memory slightly equal to your RAM size then the rest you can use it for other purposes.doing this you will have 3 partitions 500Gb,swap(equal to RAM) and the other memory. You can access gparted by sudo gparted in the terminal when in live mode using live ubuntu CD

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please guide me with more detailed steps. I am newbie to Ubuntu and many terms are new to me. I would appreciate. I have installed gParted but no idea how to use it.

Comment: I have removed partition. Please see added screen-shot in update area.

Comment: You need to boot from LiveUSb, then extend your `/` partition.

Comment: I see.. how about this?? http://askubuntu.com/questions/180730/how-do-i-restore-a-swap-partition-i-accidentally-deleted