# Resize Ubuntu 10.04 VirtualBox VM virtual disk

Tags: virtualbox

How do I resize my virtual disk space? I'm running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS with only 8GB (which is the default allocated size) but it's running low on disk space. Thanks.

---

Here's the screenshot. Thanks to @Suhaib for the +points in reputation.

[image: How to Resize Virtual Disk Image]

Comment: virtual disk space, you mean ubuntu is running as a guest in virtual box?

Comment: yes.. only 1GB left, there's a window that pops up, giving a warning..

Comment: @suhaib, that is running on WinXP..mine is Ubuntu..

Comment: @Jane did you look at the 2nd solution. Which is the command line solution ? that one is used for any hardisk. whether it is Xp or Ubuntu

Comment: Now I get this:

 `C:\Users\Se7eN\VirtualBox VMs\LUCID_LYNX>VBoxManage modifyhd 
JH.vdi --resize 10000

'VBoxManage' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: I already resolved it, but I can't upload a screenshot of what I did..need to earn more than 10 reputation..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The last 2 comments  in this forum greatly helped me, which said:

> **Oxwivi**
>
> Do I do that on Windows? Because if I do that it says:
>   `'vboxmanage' is
>   not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or
>   batch file.`
>
> **sean.dybob**
>   June 8th, 2011, 09:07 AM
>
> vboxmanage is found inside the virtualbox installation directory, should be inside
>   `C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\` directory.

These are the steps I did (Host OS is Windows):

1) **`File`** >> **`Virtual Media Manager`** >> **`Select VDI`** >> **`Release`**

2) Copy the **location** of the VDI inside the Properties box. In my case, it's:

```
C:\Users\Se7eN\VirtualBox VMs\LUCID_LYNX\JH.vdi
```

3) Go to [Google.com](http://google.com) and type your desired size in gigabyte to be converted to megabyte. For example: **10 GB = MB**

The result would be **10240**.

4) Open the command line and type/copy this:

```
cd C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox
```

This is the location of the VirtualBox software you installed in your computer.

*Notice that you have two VirtualBox folders, 1) "**VirtualBox VMs**", which contains your virtual machines, and 2) "**VirtualBox**", which is the program.*

5) Lastly, run:

```
VBoxManage modifyhd YOUR_VDI_LOCATION --resize SIZE_IN_MEGABYTES

VBoxManage modifyhd C:\Users\Se7eN\VirtualBox VMs\LUCID_LYNX\JH.vdi --resize 10240
```

I have screenshots for all of the above steps, but need to earn more than 10 reputation to upload the image. Hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the mention. Fixed thread link. :)

Comment: `modifyhd` has been deprecated for **Oracle Virtualbox version: 6.06** the correct way of doing it is to do the following command: `VBoxManage modifymedium disk "C:\Users\iin584\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu-19-HpL\Ubuntu-19-HpL.vdi" --resize 30720` (obviously replace the vdi URI with your own)

Comment: The issue however is that the guest Ubuntu does not recognize the addition of the above, even though Oracle Virtualbox succeeds in increasing the limit. I shutdown and restarted Virtualbox. If anyone has any clues it would be appreicated.

Comment: I am getting a permission error (windows 10 host, on an aadvark guest vdi file): " --resize 60999
VBoxManage.exe: error: Permission problem accessing the file for the medium 'C:\Users\Andy\VirtualBox VMs\ArtfulAadvark_17.10_fresh' (VERR_ACCESS_DENIED)
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR (0x80bb0004), component MediumWrap, interface IMedium, callee IUnknown
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "OpenMedium(Bstr(pszFilenameOrUuid).raw(), enmDevType, enmAccessMode, fForceNewUuidOnOpen, pMedium.asOutParam())" at line 179 of file VBoxManageDisk.cpp

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for sharing. The downside. It is not implemented for VMDK file type, yet.

```
PS C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox> .\VBoxManage.exe modifyhd "C:\Users\John\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu UZH DS\-disk2.vmdk" --resize 15360
VBoxManage.exe : 0%...
At line:1 char:17
+ .\VBoxManage.exe <<<<  modifyhd "C:\Users\John\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu UZH DS
\-disk2.vmdk" --resize 15360
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (0%...:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Progress state: VBOX_E_NOT_SUPPORTED

VBoxManage.exe: error: Resize hard disk operation for this format is not implem
ented yet!
```

However, you could first transform the VMDK to VDI and then resize the VDI container.

```
VBoxManage clonehd original.vmdk new.vdi --format VDI
```

Analog command applies for Linux.