# Resizing Xubuntu patrition

Tags: xubuntu, filesystem

Ok, here is the problem. I have a Xubuntu in Virtual box. I have resized the machine HD and added the missing space using GParted to the patrition as seen in this picture:

[image]

After resize the new size should be 25 GB.

However when running console I only get:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem                    Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/xubuntu--vg-root   18G   14G  2,5G  85% /
                                ^--- Size isn't increased to ~25GB --
none                          4,0K     0  4,0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev                          1,5G  4,0K  1,5G   1% /dev
tmpfs                         302M  860K  301M   1% /run
none                          5,0M     0  5,0M   0% /run/lock
none                          1,5G   80K  1,5G   1% /run/shm
none                          100M   20K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sda1                     236M   90M  134M  41% /boot
```

So the question is - how do I safely expand my current FS to full size? I need to add those missing 6GB to my primary patrition.

Comment: Hi Daniel, this will probably help you: http://askubuntu.com/questions/101715/resizing-virtual-drive

Comment: Thanks, but I already did all that (18 gig was size *before* disk was resize, new disk size is 25gig). I'm puzzled that Xubuntu doesn't notice that it's size changed!

Comment: I see, I should read more carefull...

Comment: It's okay, I was looking for that link though.