# Ubuntu black screen after booting

Tags: boot, nvidia

I updated mi ubuntu that has an Nvidia graphic car, after updating when I rebooted the computer it tries to boot but then a black screen appears.

With a live cd I entered to the "Try ubuntu without installing" option and check out the log/boot and this appears.

"(1 of 3) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-CFE2\x2d0A58.device (11s / 1min 30s)"

What I need to do to repair this?

Comment: A possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/711016/slow-boot-a-start-job-is-running-for-dev-disk-by