# edit /etc/fstab from another system

Tags: boot, root, fstab

I was trying to resolve a "slow boot" issue on my ubuntu-Windows-dual boot machine.
[Slow boot - "a start job is running for dev-disk-by..."](https://askubuntu.com/questions/711016/slow-boot-a-start-job-is-running-for-dev-disk-by)
I have edited the `fstab` file but accidentally commented out the efi-partition-uuid in it as well.

Now I want to edit the file from a live-version, but even as Root I don't get access to the file. I made a backup of the file which I just need to replace but how do I get access to /etc/ on this install drive?

Comment: Using a 'live' system such as Ubuntu install media; you should have read/write access to the installed drive; however did you mount it read-write?, is it clean? (ie. if an error is detected, a RW mounted disk becomes RO), or is it encrypted & you've not yet unlocked?   You should have access unless you've done something wrong, or skipped a required step - none of which you've provided.  I would `sudo mount` then `sudo cp -pv` etc from live.. but did you get errors for your `mount`?

Comment: I mounted the drive via the filemanager, then right-clicked `open terminal here` and typed the following: `su -` `sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab`. All I get is an error. So in my particular case I'd have to do `sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p7` ?

Comment: If you've opened a terminal in the root directory of the mounted drive, then the file you need to edit is `etc/fstab` **not** `/etc/fstab` (which will always refer to the fstab file of the *running* system)