# Ubuntu 19.10 - Long Boot Time

Tags: boot, 19.10

my PC recently had a head crash and I thought: Well, now you can try 19.10 instead of 18.04.

The beta ran well - but after release of 19.10 I realized my laptop taking about a minute to boot to login. Before, it was much faster to boot to the login screen!

I have no idea where to start looking - it is a fairly new install, maybe 3 weeks old. System drive and /home are both SSD.

--> But I do not use SWAP <-- since I heard you should not do that on SSDs and is not used other than for hibernation on most 16GB systens. Is this the culprit? It is the only change I made since going out of beta??

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I can answer my question myself :-)

It was indeed disabling SWAP - the old swap partition (which was deleted) was still entered in /etc/fstab.

So if any of you encounter a long boot time, here are my steps:

1. Press ESC while boot to see the boot log or look at the boot log /var/logs/boot.log. Look for "A start job..." this usually points to some uuid (hard disk or partion) that is not available anymore. Maybe you deleted a partition after installation?
2. Either comment out the questionable line in /etc/fstab - if you deleted the partion (or in my case: Swap Partition) or correct it if you created a new partition (which has another uuid).

You may find this link helpful: [Slow boot - "a start job is running for dev-disk-by..."](https://askubuntu.com/questions/711016/slow-boot-a-start-job-is-running-for-dev-disk-by/753571#753571)[Slow boot - "a start job is running for dev-disk-by..." - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/711016/slow-boot-a-start-job-is-running-for-dev-disk-by/753571#753571)