# How to check whether the linux system using a large disk space?

Tags: partitioning, mount, virtualbox, disk

I am using VirtualBox. I installed a ubuntu system on it. At the beginning, I set default 8GB disk space. But it's not big enough so I want to add more space on it.

I used this way(add to 20GB):

```
VBoxManage modifyhd my_ubuntu.vdi --resize 20000
```

After I restart my ubuntu, I run these commands in the terminal:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1.3G     0  1.3G   0% /dev
tmpfs           256M  4.4M  251M   2% /run
/dev/sda1       5.3G  5.0G     0 100% /
tmpfs           1.3G  224K  1.3G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           1.3G     0  1.3G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           256M   48K  256M   1% /run/user/1000

$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 19.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0  5.5G  0 part /
├─sda2   8:2    0    1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0  2.6G  0 part [SWAP]
sr0     11:0    1 55.5M  0 rom
```

Why can't I see the addition space under `df -h` command? But can see it by using `lsblk`? And, is it really that my system is 20GB available and useful now?

Comment: (Different VM software, but same principle - once you resize the disk, the filesystem needs to be resized as well)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question:

`df -h` only shows you the size of the partitions, and the contents of those partitions.

`lsblk` will show you the partitions sizes, as well as the disk they are hosted on.

You need to re-partition to use empty space.

The other answer does not explain it, but links to a possible way to [expand your filesystem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67095/how-can-i-expand-ext4-partition-size-on-debian).

Unfortunately, I cannot provide any experience on how to do this.

Further Reading:

- [Resizing Virtual drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/101715/resizing-virtual-drive/558215#558215)
- https://askubuntu.com/a/88651/606721

Answer (score 0):

Not allowed to add comment, but you might want to look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67095/how-can-i-expand-ext4-partition-size-on-debian. I believe you need to resize your root partition, `/dev/sda1`, using a utility such as `gparted` or `fdisk`.