# Ubuntu 14.04 I have resized partition and root still has very little to no disk space

Tags: 14.04, server, partitioning, virtualbox, gparted

I have Ubuntu 14.04 server running. It is running on VirtualBox 5.1.12r112440. The vdi size was 50GB but I used this link to resize it successfully to 200GB:

[Resizing Virtual drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/101715/resizing-virtual-drive)

However when I boot the VM up it says root / is next to zero disk space.

[image: Resized Virtual Box VDI]

The image shows that I have about 50GB of unallocated space in the /dev/sda5 extended partition to use for resizing the partition for root. In the GParted Live CD app thats displayed I dont see the devices /dev/sda2 - /dev/sda4. I suspect that root is one of this non listed partitions. So how do I get root more disk space?

```
df -h
Filesystem          Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                2.0G  4.0K  2.0G   1% /dev
tmpfs               396M  684K  395M   1% /run
/dev/dm-0            45G   43G  366M 100% /
none                4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none                5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                2.0G   12K  2.0G   1% /run/shm
none                100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/sda1           2.4G   47M  2.2G   3% /boot

pvdisplay
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sda5
  VG Name               matrix-ubuntu-vg
  PV Size               106.70 GiB / not usable 2.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes 
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              27314
  Free PE               14584
  Allocated PE          12730
  PV UUID               lVlrhr-IDvI-i81L-GmZp-Dj12-tx24-NjuSOZ
```

Thanks for helping!

Please refer to my answer as to why this is not answered by the "possible duplicate". The write up in the link I provided is a pretty good walk through on how to resize a LVM partition.

Comment: Your problem is that you have an LVM container and are not using raw partitions directly. The second answer offering a GUI solution to the linked question above should meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

This link answers my question: http://www.joomlaworks.net/blog/item/168-resizing-the-disk-space-on-ubuntu-server-vms

Its a good write up and works.