# How to rectify this problem /dev/sda1 is full?

Tags: 14.04, boot, 16.04, partitioning, virtualbox

I have tried using `df -h` and it resulted in

```
df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            981M     0  981M   0% /dev
tmpfs           201M  3.6M  197M   2% /run
/dev/sda1       5.8G  5.4G   67M  99% /
tmpfs          1001M  196K 1000M   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs          1001M     0 1001M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           201M   68K  200M   1% /run/user/1000
```

---

Even i cant use to download any file it shows the disk is full.I even went to expand my disk by this [Link Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/101715/resizing-virtual-drive) . And it didnt give the expanded hard disk still showing the same error.[image]

Any suggestions to fix this?

Comment: Are you sure you have enough space on your physical machine for extending the size of your virtual one? Your virtual machine should be able to get 50GB from your physical storage from which is currently using 6GB. I guess due to the lack of space in the physical machine, this space cannot be used for the virtual one.

Comment: It is brand new 1TB machine.

Comment: The virtual disk seems to be expanded to 50GB. But this does not automagically expand the partition and filesystem. So, boot the VM from an Ubuntu .iso in 'try Ubuntu' mode and run `gparted` to increase the partition and filesystem. You could do this from your running system using `fdisk` and `resize2fs`, but that is risky if you don't know what you're doing.