# Increasing size of a virtualmachine using only the command line

Tags: command-line, partitioning, virtualbox

There are countless guides and SO questions related to this question, but as far as I can find, they all use a GUI for at least some part of the answer.

I have an Ubuntu 14.4 server, to which I only have SSH access. I use this Ubuntu 14.04 as host to run a Ubuntu 12.04 guest. As such, I only use the command line for both the guest and host.

The guest is running out of disk space, and as such I whish to increase the current 200gb to 400gb.

```
VBoxManage modifyhd /data_nfs/VM/Ubuntu.vdi  --resize 400000
```

Increasing the `vdi` size is easy, but for the next steps, I can only find instructions on how to do it using a GUI, like in this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/101715/resizing-virtual-drive/558215#558215). How can I do this from the command line?