# VirtualBox Ubuntu Guest Windows 7 host - resizing virtual machine

Tags: partitioning, virtualbox

I was carefully following the instructions at:

[Resizing Virtual drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/101715/resizing-virtual-drive)

but got stuck at 3.6. I can't resize the root partition (/dev/sda1)  because it is mounted.

I tried booting my virtual machine using a gparted liveCD, but VirtualBox refused to boot from the CD.

Comment: VBox refusing to boot from the CD is a different problem.  Try booting to the Ubuntu installation disk instead of a gparted disk?  Assuming you have a graphical installation, that might be the 'fastest' way to get to a usable environment for adjusting the partitions.

Comment: What is the error? " VirtualBox refused to boot from the CD"

Comment: I tried booting from the Ubuntu installation disk and got the same message, "FATAL: Could not read from the boot medium! System halted.