# Error: You don't have enough free space in /var/cache/apt/archives/

Tags: apt, pip

I am trying to use Ubuntu 20.04 in Oracle Virtualbox. I am unable to use pip or pip3 as it raises an error:

```
Error:pip3 command not found
```

I tried installing, but failed.

```
$ sudo easy_install pip3
Error: easy_install command not found.
```

When I tried using:
`

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3-pip
Error: Package 'python3-pip' has no installation candidate.
```

Then I ran this command :

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then when I ran the following command I got an error:

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
ERROR: You don't have enough free space in /var/cache/apt/archives/
```

The output of `df -H` command is:

[image: This is my terminal screen]

Please help, I want to install pip on my virtual machine (ubuntu)

Comment: Well, you only have 0.4 G available on `/cow`, and the system needs to download 579MB. So that's not going to work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I increase the hard disk size of the virtual machine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88647/how-do-i-increase-the-hard-disk-size-of-the-virtual-machine) and [Resizing Virtual drive](https://askubuntu.com/q/101715/)

Answer (score 0):

You can clean the apt cache using:

```
 sudo apt-get clean
```