# /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root is full

Tags: disk-usage

I have just successfully increased my disk size having had help [with this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/433657/increase-space-for-ubuntu-server-on-virtualbox). My set up is Ubuntu Server running in VirtualBox as a web development server. I now have this space:

[image]

As you can see `/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root` is full but I have a a lot more space. How do I go about using the new space to stop disk full errors? I am not even sure where to start looking so any help is great.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I resize partitions using command line without using a GUI on a server?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/390769/how-do-i-resize-partitions-using-command-line-without-using-a-gui-on-a-server)

Comment: @Lucio I have a similar result, but already used `gparted` on a LiveCD to increase `/dev/sda`, but the `/dev/mapper` root partition is still the same size. There  more going on here than needing a resize.

Comment: you have to resize the root partition /dev/mapper/ubuntu-vg-root

Answer (score 10):

`/dev/mapper` indicates that you're using LVM; so resizing the physical volume is not enough to resize the *logical* volume contained within, let alone the filesystem.

To increase the filesystem size, I followed [these instructions](https://serverfault.com/a/38567/85654) from ServerFault with success:

1. First, I increased the physical partition using `gparted`. This was straightforward, and I assume you've already done that. If you don't have access to a LiveCD, you can increase the size of the physical disk while online, via `pvresize`, as shown in the linked instructions.
2. Then I used `lvresize` to grow the logical volume to fill the physical volume. I used `pvdisplay` to verify the size of the physical volume, and tried using that size.

   ```
    sudo lvresize -L 28.82G /dev/ubuntu-tt-vg/root
   ```

However, it was too large, so I started with 27G, and kept resizing my partition bigger until I hit the max.

3. Then, I used `resize2fs` to grow the filesystem inside the logical volume.

   ```
    sudo resize2fs /dev/ubuntu-tt-vg/root 7290881
   ```

Finding the max here was much easier. If you try a number bigger than the max, it will tell you exactly what the max is.

4. At this point, `df -h` should show that your filesystem has grown to the new size.

Comment: Nice tip with '*If you try a number bigger than the max, it will tell you exactly what the max is.*', I just went `sudo resize2fs /dev/mapper/kubuntu--vg-root 999999999999` as a result.