LXD containers fail to start and can't create new ones (out of space despite >800GiB free space)
hooly@ubuntu-lts:~$ lxc start sfserver
Error: saving config file for the container failed
Try `lxc info --show-log sfserver` for more info
    
hooly@ubuntu-lts:~$ lxc info --show-log sfserver
Name: sfserver
Status: STOPPED
Type: container
Architecture: x86_64
Created: 2024/09/18 05:27 UTC
Last Used: 2024/10/16 10:41 UTC
        
Log:
        
hooly@ubuntu-lts:~$ lxc console sfserver --show-log
Error: open /var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/logs/sfserver/console.log: no such file or directory
        
hooly@ubuntu-lts:~$ sudo df -h
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                               13G  1,5M   13G   1% /run
efivarfs                           128K   48K   76K  39% /sys/firmware/efi/efivars
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv  886G   39G  810G   5% /
tmpfs                               63G     0   63G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5,0M     0  5,0M   0% /run/lock
/dev/nvme0n1p2                     2,0G  183M  1,7G  10% /boot
/dev/nvme0n1p1                     1,1G  6,2M  1,1G   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs                              1,0M     0  1,0M   0% 

/var/snap/lxd/common/ns
tmpfs                               13G   12K   13G   1% /run/user/1000

hooly@ubuntu-lts:~$ lxc launch ubuntu:24.04 sfserver2
Creating sfserver2
Error: Failed instance creation: Failed creating instance from image: Failed to run: zfs create -o mountpoint=legacy -o canmount=noauto default/images/74957a5580288913be8a8727d121f16616805e3183629133029ca907f210f541: exit status 1 (cannot create 'default/images/74957a5580288913be8a8727d121f16616805e3183629133029ca907f210f541': out of space)

During installation of Ubuntu Server 24.04 it automatically used only a fraction of my NVMe, so I had to manually resize the logical volume. Despite now having 810GiB of storage available, all containers fail to start with the non-descriptive error of "Out of space". df shows a significant amount of free storage that is ostensibly unavailable for unknown reasons.

Welcome to ASK. I suspect you are using Logical Volume Management  LVM. Resizing the LVM partition does not resize the dynamic partitions (logical volume) within it.  Please see the answer to question at this link https://askubuntu.com/questions/433705/dev-mapper-ubuntu-vg-root-is-full for more details of how to do this.
