# How to increase VM HDD and RAM sizes?

Tags: virtualization

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 VM on VirtualBox. I used this VM for several weeks. I need to increase its RAM and HDD size. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For memory at least, this can be done in the settings for the VM - in 4.3.10 atleast, this can be found under 'System':
[image: screenshot - look under 'System' for base memory]

You may also want to increase the video memory:
[image: screenshot - look under 'Display' for video memory]

For the hard disk, if you chose 'Dynamically Allocated' it should automatically increase its size up to the fixed size you gave it when you first set up the VM. You may be able to resize it with `modifyhd` or something else - see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/716649/how-to-change-fixed-size-vdi-with-modifyhd-command-in-windows) or [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88647/how-do-i-increase-the-hard-disk-size-of-the-virtual-machine). A bit more information on that can be found [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch05.html#vdidetails). You can view info on the VM's storage under 'Storage' in settings:
[image]

Comment: The guest OS has to be off (not in a saved state) in order to have the memory options enabled.

Comment: Very good comment !

Answer (score 1):

sure you can.

To add some more ram to the VM press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd> and type **virtualbox**.

Select desired VM and got to **"Settings"** menu. After go to system and on the right you will be able to increase RAM.

It is not so easy to resize HDD, here is a good [how-to](http://www.my-guides.net/en/guides/general-software/how-to-resize-a-virtualbox-disk-partition) with screenshots.

Comment: no need to show how to open virtual box

Comment: The link is dead

Answer (score 0):

**It worked for me**
Read this link, explained clearly with screenshots

https://itsfoss.com/increase-disk-size-virtualbox/