# VirtualBox Xubuntu guest does not recognise changed virtual disk size

Tags: partitioning, virtualbox, xubuntu

I am running a Xubuntu 14.04 guest in VirtualBox (on a Win 7 host).

The virtual disk ("Dynamically allocated") filled up, so I followed [this answer using `VBoxManage modifyhd`](https://askubuntu.com/a/88651/181442) to increase its size, which was easy.

Next time I started the Xubuntu guest however didn't show any free space on the drive, also `gparted` still shows the old disk size.

What do I have to do to make the guest recognise that the size has changed so it can make use of the added space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had this problem a bunch of times. It's hard to say exactly why it's happening without screenshots of what your gparted looks like. In my case it was usually because resizing a virtual hard disk actually takes two steps.

You did the first step, which was to resize the virtual hard disk through VBoxManage. What I'd recommend next is opening up gparted and checking for any "unallocated space" on the hard disk. For Xubuntu to start using the extra space that was made available through VBoxManage, you have to use the "Resize" function to turn that "unallocated space" into space that's formatted for Linux to use.

Apologies if you checked that already--if so, are you using LVM by any chance?

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes, I am using LVM. I had to go through the following steps in `gparted`: 1) Use the "Swapoff" feature on the swap partition to unlock the partition editing. 2) Grow the volume which includes the `swap` partition to fill all the "unallocated space". 3) Move the `swap` partition inside that volume to the very end and 4) shrink the volume from the left to include just the `swap` which is on the far right. This resulted in "unallocated space" between the main partition and the volume with `swap`. 5) So I could grow the main partition to fill the free space and voila, I had space available again!