# My disc in ubuntu is full

Tags: virtualbox

I am currently working on a project with a lot of data in a Virtual box(Ubuntu). I downloaded some of the data from the terminal to the desktop. However, suddenly the terminal told me: "Not enough disc space available". I tried to delete some of the data just locally on the ubuntu desktop but in the terminal, it still told me: "Not enough disc space". I tried to shut the virtual box down. When I restarted it there is only a black screen. The desktop doesn't load because there is not enough disc space. I have tried with crtl+alt+f1 and this gives the terminal login page. The problem is I have no clue what my login is since I haven't created one.

What am I going to do?

Please help me I am totally stuck right now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I increase the hard disk size of the virtual machine?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88647/how-do-i-increase-the-hard-disk-size-of-the-virtual-machine)

Comment: FYI you *have* created a login - when you installed Ubuntu in the VM. Since you were working in a terminal, your login name (username) should have been shown in the default terminal prompt e.g. `username@computername:~$ `

Answer (score 0):

To get it to boot, you can restart your computer into single user mode to clean up. turn the computer on, at the grub screen hit e to edit the entry. add 'single' to the end of the first grub line and press alt+x to boot. Your system will boot and you can use df -h to see the amount of free space, and du -sh /* to see what directory branches have the most stuff in then that you need to remove some of to get your computer to boot again.
  To find out what your username is, just look in /etc/passwd while in single user mode. Use "passwd " to change the password of the user if you don't know it.