# VirtualBox - all virtual hard disk (vdi) already full...though 2 never used?

Tags: partitioning, virtualbox, hard-drive

I have already browsed quite a bit to find a solution - but ran into several problems.

I have three VM (Windows Host).

- Ubuntu 16, 32bit, I don't use it at all
- Ubuntu 16, 64bit. (Installed: MongoDB, Node, NPM, Vim, Git)
- Nothing yet, it should be for Ubuntu Server later.

When I run my VM Ubuntu-64 a message appears saying there's only 300 mb left one the hard disk, which is strange given that *the previous message gave even less.*

I tried to go into the vdi file (on windows) to edit it don't know how (tried Notepad - sorry if it's a silly attempt - but it says too large to be opened).

But on top of all that I don't understand how **all three virtual hard disks can show "virtual size 8GB" and "actual size 8GB"** when I haven't used all three of them at all - or not that much? (The VM I've used these past few days is maybe...three days old!!)

I'm really scared of trying anything just based on what I find - I'd really like not to have to go through the whole installation of my programs again.

Can anyone help me? I really apologize for the newbie question - but I'd really like to continue using that VM (the 64bit), I'm having the time of my life learning Linux commands and all.

UPDATE - removed Ubuntu 32 and Server VMs

This is the output of `df -h`

```
~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            630M     0  630M   0% /dev
tmpfs           130M  4,4M  126M   4% /run
/dev/sda1       6,5G  5,7G  460M  93% /
tmpfs           649M  236K  648M   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           649M     0  649M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
sharedbox       373G   83G  290G  23% /media/sf_sharedbox
tmpfs           130M   52K  130M   1% /run/user/1000
```

[UPDATE] Follow the steps given by @heynnema below !

Comment: Could you update your question with the output of 'df -h' from a terminal in your VM ?

Comment: 8GB is really tight. Just by installing a few updates and other software you will be running out of space soon.

Comment: Ok...what should I do to at least save some of my installs? It may sounds silly but I've already spent so much time!

Comment: The `df-h` appears to have been run from your hose machine, not one of the *VM* machines.  Will you give the output of the `df -h` from one of the *VMs* you are trying to save?

Comment: @L.D.James Not at all, I ran df -h from the VM, Ubuntu Guest, I promise. I really can't confuse the black thing in Windows and the nice thing on Ubuntu!

Comment: Thanks for the response.  On closer look I see the "373G" resource is a share, not a drive.  I'll test and and format the steps I have used to resolve this issue and post it soon, if your issue is still unresolved.

Comment: @L.D.James thanks a lot - I don't think I'll try anything else just yet - well actually I've just tried to install and run ubuntu-tweak but failed :)

Comment: Ubuntu-tweak is now abandonware and should not be used on current versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: You're welcome.  Heynnema just posted the resolution I was formatting for you.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please don't edit your post and add `Solved` to the title. Instead, just mark one of the posts below as the correct answer by clicking the check-mark below the vote count of the post that solved your problem.

Comment: To increase the size of an exisiting VDI see https://askubuntu.com/questions/88647/how-do-i-increase-the-hard-disk-size-of-the-virtual-machine. Note that this will require a re-partitioning of the virtual drive. It is easier to start from scratch with a much larger dynamically growing VDI (20-30 GB). Also see https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html

Answer (score 2):

The default size for dynamic disks created in Virtualbox is 8GB. This is usually not enough for most guest operating systems to thrive. Sometimes you need to increase the dynamic disk size, after initial creation, and we use the `vboxmanage` command.

In Windows, to see the vboxmanage commands, in an **administrative** command prompt window, type:

```
"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" /?
```

To change dynamic disk sizes, we do, like so:

```
cd path_to_where_your_vdi_is_located

then

"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" modifymedium disk your_vdi_name.vdi --resize megabytes
or
"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" modifymedium disk your_vdi_name.vdi --resizebyte bytes
```

- Change `your_vdi_name.vdi` to the filename of your dynamic disk.
- Change `megabytes` or `bytes` to the final desired size.
- note: `modifyhd` was used in older versions of vboxmanage.

Once the .vdi dynamic disk has been enlarged, you need to actually increase the Ubuntu partition size to fully use the extra space. Boot the VM to a Ubuntu Live .iso image *(by mounting it in the "CD" drive)*, select `Try Ubuntu`, and use `gparted` to set the swap partition to `swapoff` and then to `move` the swap partition to the right *(if it's to the right side of the Ubuntu partition)*, and `resize` the Ubuntu partition on /dev/sda1 to its maximum size. *(note: if the Ubuntu and swap partitions reside in an extended partition, you'll have to resize that first).*

Comment: fair enough and I will but I'm still wondering whether it's normal it went full so fast given how little I've done with it?

Comment: Being as your root only has 460M left, yes.

Comment: I've run exactly that but it says invalid command 'disk' ..

Comment: Do the `vboxmanage /?` to see the exact format for the `modifymedium` command in Windows. In Windows they may not use/need the `disk` portion of the command like you do in a Ubuntu host. I'll re-edit...

Comment: It shows exactly that : disk | dvd |  floppy . Damn ! it was so close :)

Comment: Did you get it done? What final command did you use? I'll re-edit again for posterity...

Comment: Changed the path a little - I had VirtualBox\VMs (that's how I access it) but had to be like you said (sorry, I assumed I had a different path) but now I have Access Denied. So now I'm browsing to see how I can change that :)

Comment: The path shown is for the .exe... you probably have to `cd path_where_your_vdi_is` first... I'll re-edit one more time...

Comment: Ok I've done it all again, now it says something interesting: VBOX_E_NOT SUPPORTED, rebox sizing not implemented yet!

Comment: Compare my last edit of the `modifymedium` command with what the `vboxmanage /?` says... I swear its got to be right. Make sure it uses `modifymedium` and not `modifyhd`.

Comment: I've triple checked I swear. Your commands are absolutely fine (I wouldn't have had that error message otherwise), it must be something in my files and/or it half worked and the resizing is now buggy.  I suggest we close the thread here as it has an answer and my problem is now elseswhere! I'll edit my original post so as not to link to the other thread. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: OK, but please let me know the final fix/outcome. Put `@heynnema` at the start of any new comment to make sure that I see it.

Comment: This will only increase the size of the VDI but it will not increase the size of the partition we had installed Ubuntu.

Comment: @Takkat correct, then you have to use gparted to increase the partition size. I'll edit my answer to include that.

Comment: Now swap will likely stand  in the way of growing the Ubuntu partition.... It is much easier to just create a new install.

Comment: @Takkat dang, you're right... Re-edit... The user prefers not to start a new install because of the programs installed in the current VM... but you're right again.