# Ubuntu freezes and notifies low disk space

Tags: partitioning, virtualbox, disk-usage

I have Ubuntu installed via virtualbox on windows7. Ubuntu tends to frequently freeze. In addition in each boot there is a *low disk space* notification, which may be related.
The storage is configured dynamically as far as i see. and i think i configured it to 10GB. Attached [the setting image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPWDr.png)  showing it has 10GB virtual size and 10GB actual size. 
Also attached [disk analysis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYBMm.png)
And attaching [df-h](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XK45b.png) (which i didn't know how to paste here in a readable way)

In addition this is what lsblk outputs:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0    7:0    0 140.7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/82
loop1    7:1    0 140.7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/74
loop2    7:2    0   3.7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-system-monitor/70
loop3    7:3    0 294.2M  1 loop /snap/pycharm-community/121
loop4    7:4    0   2.3M  1 loop /snap/gnome-calculator/260
loop5    7:5    0  1008K  1 loop /snap/gnome-logs/61
loop6    7:6    0    13M  1 loop /snap/gnome-characters/139
loop7    7:7    0 295.9M  1 loop /snap/pycharm-community/123
loop8    7:8    0  53.7M  1 loop /snap/core18/941
loop9    7:9    0    91M  1 loop /snap/core/6405
loop10   7:10   0   3.7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-system-monitor/57
loop11   7:11   0     4M  1 loop /snap/gnome-calculator/406
loop12   7:12   0  91.1M  1 loop /snap/core/6531
loop13   7:13   0  34.8M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1122
loop14   7:14   0   151M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/31
loop15   7:15   0 140.7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/78
loop16   7:16   0  53.7M  1 loop /snap/core18/782
loop17   7:17   0  89.3M  1 loop /snap/core/6673
loop18   7:18   0   3.7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-system-monitor/77
loop19   7:19   0   151M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/36
loop20   7:20   0  14.5M  1 loop /snap/gnome-logs/45
loop21   7:21   0  35.3M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1198
loop22   7:22   0  34.6M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/818
loop23   7:23   0  14.8M  1 loop /snap/gnome-characters/254
loop24   7:24   0  14.8M  1 loop /snap/gnome-characters/206
loop25   7:25   0  1008K  1 loop /snap/gnome-logs/57
loop26   7:26   0     4M  1 loop /snap/gnome-calculator/352
loop27   7:27   0 143.5M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/23
sda      8:0    0    10G  0 disk 
└─sda1   8:1    0    10G  0 part /
sr0     11:0    1    82M  0 rom  /media/yoni/VBox_GAs_6.0.4
```

my questions:

1. Is the slowness and especially frequent freezing of the system relates to the low disk space?
2. If answer to 1 is yes, how do i increase disk space?
3. If the answer to 1 is no and i can ignore the disk space issue (or should i solve it anyway?) what can solve my Ubuntu from constant freezing?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. You have exhausted your 10G disk space. Ubuntu can't run well when disk free is at 0, so the slowdown and problems is expected when this happens. You should shutdown the VM, increase the disk allocation of this VM using the Oracle VM Virtualbox app, and then power on the VM.

Comment: How do i increase the disk allocation of this VM?

Comment: How to resize vdi size has already been answered before, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/88647/how-do-i-increase-the-hard-disk-size-of-the-virtual-machine It should provide enought info to help you do the job. See the answer with the step `VBoxManage modifyhd YOUR_HARD_DISK.vdi --resize SIZE_IN_MB`

Comment: already seen it, but when tried .\VBoxManage modifyhd "C:\Users\Administrator\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu\Ubuntu.vdi" --resize 20000 i got the following: VBoxManage.exe: error: Failed to resize medium
VBoxManage.exe: error: Resizing to new size 20971520000 is not yet supported for
 medium 'C:\Users\Administrator\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu\Ubuntu.vdi'
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code VBOX_E_NOT_SUPPORTED (0x80bb0009), componen
t MediumWrap, interface IMedium
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "enum RTEXITCODE __cdecl handleModifyMedium(stru
ct HandlerArg *)" at line 768 of file VBoxManageDisk.cpp

Comment: Make sure you have virtualbox version 4.0 or newer. I believe eariler version does not support resizing. If you are already using version later than 4.0, you may try clonehd to make a new disk, resize that disk, then attack the new disk to the vm and then remove the old disk in the vm.

Comment: i have virtualbox 6.0 it tried cloning, and then resizing the cloned vdi. the result was: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox>.\VBoxManage modifyhd "C:\Users\Administrator
\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu Clone\Ubuntu Clone.vdi" --resize 20000
VBoxManage.exe: error: Failed to create the VirtualBox object!
VBoxManage.exe: error: The object is not ready
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_ACCESSDENIED (0x80070005), component Virt
ualBoxClientWrap, interface IVirtualBoxClient

Comment: some more update, i tried few more things and after detaching and re-attaching the vdi, and restoring latest snapshot now the message i get is: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox>.\VBoxManage modifyhd "C:\Users\Administrator
\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu\Ubuntu.vdi" --resize 20000
VBoxManage.exe: error: Failed to create the VirtualBox object!
VBoxManage.exe: error: The object is not ready
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_ACCESSDENIED (0x80070005), component Virt
ualBoxClientWrap, interface IVirtualBoxClient

Comment: Strange you got the access denied, do you have read/write access to that vdi file and that directory? Also make sure the VM is powered down.