# Change boot disk on Ubuntu VM

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning

I have a sandbox Ubuntu server VM (virtualbox) with a single drive. Recently I needed to extend the disk space of the server, so I created a second disk. I `dd`'d the original `/dev/sda` to the new `/dev/sdb` and extended the partition size with `parted` and `resize2fs`. Everything looks great, so now I want to make the `/dev/sdb` partition default and remove the `/dev/sda`. How do I make the `/dev/sdb` the default boot option? Currently I can only boot into it from a rescuecd, the default boot option is `/dev/sda`

`lsblk` output (booted from /dev/sdb via rescuecd):

```
[12:10] [vhost2 ~] # lsblk 
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0    10G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0     1M  0 part 
└─sda2   8:2    0    10G  0 part 
sdb      8:16   0    20G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0     1M  0 part 
└─sdb2   8:18   0  18.6G  0 part /
```

`fdisk` output:

```
[12:10] [vhost2 ~] # fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 10 GiB, 10737418240 bytes, 20971520 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 4E763705-333C-4EE0-80EB-782C5D968F03

Device     Start      End  Sectors Size Type
/dev/sda1   2048     4095     2048   1M BIOS boot
/dev/sda2   4096 20969471 20965376  10G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/sdb: 20 GiB, 21474836480 bytes, 41943040 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 4E763705-333C-4EE0-80EB-782C5D968F03

Device     Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1   2048     4095     2048    1M BIOS boot
/dev/sdb2   4096 39062500 39058405 18.6G Linux filesystem
```

My `fstab` is empty

```
[12:11] [vhost2 ~] # cat /etc/fstab 
UUID=88fdcaac-dcfd-4f0e-99de-5adf19d4ab12 / ext4 defaults 0 0
/swap.img   none    swap    sw  0   0
```

Comment: isn't that something to do inside virtualbox? you copied the disk so you don't need to have the original mounted. just tell virtualbox that that copy is it's disk and what it should boot. perhaps you should provide more context to your post. I'm supposing from what you're saying this isn't a system created in Virtualbox, it is bootable on your whole machine but also you're able to load it up from another OS using virtualbox, correct?

Comment: Hi. No, it's just a simple setup of VMs in my virtualbox. Removing the original disk from VM did the trick flawlessly. I think I overthought the whole process and I could do that much easier and faster, haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) should provide an easy, semi-automated solution here.

1. Detach your old drive from the VM (to prevent adding further work at the end).
2. Boot the live medium and run the recommended repair in [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).
3. Power off the VM and detach the live CD.
4. Your new drive should boot normally.
5. Fix your [`/etc/fstab`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab) if necessary. It should point to your actual root partition’s UUID. The current contents look well (if the UUID of your partition is correct), the file is definitely not “empty”.

If cloning the drive using `dd` wasn’t a necessary part of your sandbox experiments, you could have just [extended the original virtual hard drive](https://askubuntu.com/q/88647/250300) instead of cloning it. Of course, this approach is not feasible with physical hard-drives.

Comment: Yep, looks like I did not need to do many of the steps I did. Thanks, works great!