# Flashing curser can't login today

Tags: drivers, nvidia, login, xorg

Here I am on my phone.
I have Ubuntu studio 20.04 closed down last night and today I get:
Loading  initial  ramdisk,

Then just flashing curser.
I can get to ctrl Alt F1 and login.

Startx gives :
Fatal error.
Addscreen/Screeninit failed for driver 0

Unsble to connect x server : connection refused.

I'm totally stumped on this.

Anyone any ideas? Will I have to re install the os?

Some if the suggestions re this are over 10 years old, do we still use Xorg?
I have an Nvidia card and has been working for nearly a year.
I don't seem to have a Xorg. Conf file to look at.
I was using the Nvidia driver and don't know how to change that to Nv.
Hope you can help.

Cheers Bob

Comment: Sounds like the video card blew. Or at least some how the driver did. BTW there is no version 20 do you mean 20.04?

Comment: Please clarify you release; it doesn't exist (Ubuntu uses *yy* format releases for *snap* only releases, Ubuntu Studio is a desktop and has never had a *snap* only release). `startx` implies you attempted to start Xorg  (otherwise you'd be using a different command; the X being the same as X in Xorg). Nvidia closed source drivers mandated xorg for most past releases (but you didn't specify if you're using open-source or closed-source drivers).  Please be specific with details

Comment: sorry yes it's 20.04 LTS and the video card is fine as I can use a live usb. I have re installed 20.04 and now get a grub error 'grub calloc not found. My system has been rock solid for over a year.

Comment: Hi I was using the Nvidia drivers. I tried changing to NV but had no effect.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix a grub boot error : "symbol 'grub\_calloc' not found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1263125/how-to-fix-a-grub-boot-error-symbol-grub-calloc-not-found)

Comment: Please edit your question and correct and add additional detail there. Also please be precise & accurate, especially if you want specific advice for your actual error & release.

Comment: I am just doing a clean install of 20.04.2 and this is the error I get. it's a clean install so I have no control of where Grub installs. This has never happened before. I have cleared S and install to this. Same error. I get no error when the installation files are checked.